# FileChooser in actionListeners

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I am trying to code a small text editor and I was building the GUI.

I added a `JMenu` and added a `JMenuItem` to it. I gave the menu item the value of "open".
The reason is because I want that when "open" is pressed a `JFileChooser` appears on the screen

Here is what I have:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    JFileChooser fs = new JFileChooser();
}
```

This method is in a class called listener which implements `MouseListener`. This is the step that I'm stuck at.

```
getContentPane()
```

..does not work:

Is it good code practice the way I'm approaching this? Is there a better way? If not how do I go around doing this?

Comment: If it implements MouseListener then it is not an ActionListener. Also define "does not work".

Comment: A hint for future questions. Try to put together a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in general your approach could work, you might want to look into the Swing concept of [Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). JMenuItem has direct support for actions, you would not need a MouseListener (which is a bit to low-level for your usecase).

Try to look at the examples, it might look a little overwhelming at first, but in the end it is a nice and clean encapsulation of what you want. And it is reusable, meaning you could use the action on a different menu (maybe the context menu) as well.

And for your code, you are missing the call to `fs.showOpenDialog(component)`.

Comment: Thank you. I went and looked into Actions. One feature of them I'm not that sure is weather I should make an Action for every single action that I want to monitor or just make one and " if else " to check what action was the one performed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use a `MouseListener` for `JMenuItem` or `JButton`, this is not the appropriate means for managing these components, instead, use an `ActionListener`.

The main reason for this is that your menu item could be triggered via a keyboard shortcut or programmatically.

Secondly *"does not work"* is not information about what you problem is, but I assume it's because the method does not exist.

A simply solution would be to check the source the event to determine if it's a `Component` or not and use it instead, or `null` if the source of the event is not a `Component`...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    Component parent = null;
    if (source instanceof Component) {
        parent = (Component)source;
    }

    // Show file chooser dialog...
}
```

Take a look at [How to use menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details

You may also find [How to use actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) of some interest

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Javadoc on the JFileChooser class. It has an example of how to open it.

> The following code pops up a file chooser for the user's home directory that sees only .jpg and .gif images:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```